# Nothing happends on post_update

Tags: functions

When I'm adding a new entry to my custom post type - new category is created.

Now I'm trying to change category title when my custom post type is changed/updated, but this code doesn't work at all. Is there anything else I can try?

```
function check_values($post_ID, $post_after, $post_before){
    $myPostAfter = $post_after;
    $myPostBefore = $post_before;


    $titleBeforeUpdateID = get_cat_ID( $myPostBefore->post_title );
    $catSlug = sanitize_title( $myPostAfter->post_title, '' );

    if( term_exists($myPostBefore->post_title, 'category') ):

        wp_update_term($titleBeforeUpdateID, array(
            'name' => $myPostAfter->post_title,
            'slug' => $catSlug
        ));

    endif;

    echo 'Post ID:';
    var_dump($post_ID);
    echo 'Post Object AFTER update:';
    var_dump($post_after);
    echo 'Post Object BEFORE update:';
    var_dump($post_before);
}

add_action( 'post_updated', 'check_values', 10, 3 );
```

Error:

Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in ...\taxonomy.php on line 239

Line 239:

```
/**
 * Checks that the taxonomy name exists.
 *
 * Formerly is_taxonomy(), introduced in 2.3.0.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @global array $wp_taxonomies The registered taxonomies.
 *
 * @param string $taxonomy Name of taxonomy object.
 * @return bool Whether the taxonomy exists.
 */
function taxonomy_exists( $taxonomy ) {
    global $wp_taxonomies;

    return isset( $wp_taxonomies[$taxonomy] );
}
```

But `$myPostBefore->post_title` and `$myPostAfter->post_title` return strings in var_dump.

Comment: "Nothing happens" or "it does not work" says very little about the issue. Can you explain further what you are trying to do? The code you posted use core "category" taxonomy, which is not supported by custom post types by default. Have you added support for core "categories" to your CPT or are you using a custom taxonomy? Also, why do you want categories with the same title that posts? That is strange. One more thing, be carefull with `'slug' => $titleAfterUpdate`, [titles should be sanitized to be used on slugs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title).

Comment: I've updated the code above. I've support for categories and revisions in my cpt. Now functions returns data for prev and next title but now it seems that I have problem with updating   taxonomy?

Comment: Ahh, and I'm using the "core" categories.

Comment: wp_update_term there should be 3 parametrs: `$term_id, $taxonomy, $args`, you'r not specifying taxonomy..

Comment: How could I've missed that :) Now it works, thanks!

Comment: @Maikal, if you have the answer, post it as an answer, not as a comment please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_update_term` there should be 3 parametrs: `$term_id, $taxonomy, $args`, you'r not specifying **taxonomy**..